# Header on pages. (wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

(my site is http://www.musaeus.dk/)
I have a Wordpress.org site and I want to make a button that takes the user back to the front page but I really can't figure out how. The button should be up in the top left corner and it shouldn't be on the front page.

If have tried putting this in the "header.php" file

```
<?php if(is_page(<page id>)) { ?>

--------- Header 1 -----

<?php } else { ?>


--------- Header 2 -------- 


<?php } ?>
```

but with no luck. If you have any ideas or know how I should do this I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: we need a more complete code and the HTML output you get ti be able to help you

Comment: To hide it from your homepage, change your `if` to use the built-in Wordpress functions for detecting the homepage: `if ( ! (is_front_page()) && !(is_home()) ) `

Answer (score 0):

in your `header.php` file do something like this:

```
<?php
// check to see we are not on front page or on home page
if ( ! ( is_front_page() ) || ! ( is_home() ) ) : ?>
    <div class="back-to-home">
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">Back to Home</a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and then style `back-to-home` class to match your needs.

Comment: that made the button, but it appears on all pages including the front page. Do you know how to make it not visible on the front page?

Comment: @MaltheMusaeus it should not appear on front page, are you selecting your home page in `Settings > Reading > A static page` ?

Comment: Yes I have set a custom page as my home page

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should works.

```
<?php
    /**
     * If page is front page,
     * don't display button "Back to Home"
     */
    if ( is_front_page() ) : 
        $btn = false;
    else :
        $btn = true;
    endif;

    if ( $btn === true ) : ?>

        <div class="back-to-home">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Back to Home</a>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS:

```
.home .back-to-home {
  display: none;
}
```

The `.home` class is (only) in the `body` tag of your homepage, so that rule with this combined selector will hide the `.back-to-home` element only on the homepage